# expected dense_8 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a multi-channel 1D CNN for analyzing ECG signals. I have 258 12 lead ECGs with length 300 samples, so my input dimension is (258, 300, 12).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=20, verbose=1, validation_split = 0.2)
```

I'm running the code above, and getting the following error

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where is the error occurring? What have you tried to debug this? I recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: What shape does your training data have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to train the model like this,

`model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=20, verbose=1, validation_split = 0.2)`

The shape of `y_train` is something like `(n, 1)`, where `n` is the number of samples used to train.

Now, you are building a model with last layer like this,

```
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

From the error message, it can be deduced that you are setting `num_classes=2`. So, the last layer will have `2` nodes. Such a model expects `y_train` to be of shape `(n,2)`. But you are using `y_train` of shape `(n,1)`.

In order to fix the error, you can change the last layer as,

```
num_classes = 1
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Note that, the activation function should be changed to `sigmoid`.

Comment: Happy to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are solving a binary classification problem.
The error message indicates our model expects label with shape `(2,)` and i assume you are using `num_classes=2`. However, Your label is either `1` or `0` as the provided shape of label is `(1,)`. To solve this error, you have yo change the output dense layer of your model, and the layer should have one neuron with `sigmoid` activation function.

```
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))  # num_classes=1
```